# Amazon Web Services Beanstalk and Custom Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

When using a Beanstalk environment setup with an elastic load balancer, in Route 53 do I choose an A record with the endpoint of the elastic load balancer or of the beanstalk environment itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create A record as Alias to Beanstalk environment itself.

Comment: Yes both of it works, but somehow if your load balancer url get changed by beanstalk environment, your DNS Record will be invalid.

Comment: And linking it to the environment will route it correctly through the load balancer right?